# Why my MysqlDataReader object becoming null?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, mysqldatareader

I have the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DataBaseModule.General
{
    public class ManagedDataReader : IDisposable
    {

        private bool _disposed = false;
        private MySqlCommand _command;

        private MySqlDataReader _dataReader;
        // The class constructor.
        public ManagedDataReader(string StrSQL)
            : this(new MySqlCommand(StrSQL))
        {
        }

        public ManagedDataReader(MySqlCommand SQL_Cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                _command = SQL_Cmd;
                _command.Connection = new MySqlConnection(DbAccessProvider._connectionString);
                DbAccessProvider.SqlCommandsPerformed++;
                _command.Connection.Open();
                _dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DataBaseModule.Log.CommonLogger.Log_Database_Error(new Exception("Sql command Was: " + _command.CommandText, ex));
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public int VisibleFieldCount()
        {
            return _dataReader.VisibleFieldCount;
        }

        public bool Read()
        {
            return _dataReader.Read();
        }

        public object this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dataReader[i].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _dataReader[i];
                }
            }
        }

        public object this[string FieldName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dataReader[FieldName].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _dataReader[FieldName];
                }
            }
        }

        // Implement IDisposable.
        // Do not make this method virtual.
        // A derived class should not be able to override this method.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
            // take this object off the finalization queue 
            // and prevent finalization code for this object
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
        // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly
        // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
        // can be disposed.
        // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the 
        // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference 
        // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.
        protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
                // and unmanaged resources.
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_dataReader != null)
                    {
                        _dataReader.Close();
                    }
                    if (_command != null)
                    {
                        if (_command.Connection != null)
                        {
                            _command.Connection.Dispose();
                            _command.Connection = null;
                            //Free the reference.
                        }
                        _command.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                // Call the appropriate methods to clean up 
                // unmanaged resources here.
                // If disposing is false, 
                // only the following code is executed.
                // Note disposing has been done.
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        // This finalizer will run only if the Dispose method 
        // does not get called.
        // It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize.
        // Do not provide finalize methods in types derived from this class.
        ~ManagedDataReader()
        {
            // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here.
            // Calling Dispose(false) is optimal in terms of
            // readability and maintainability.
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that for some reason, sometimes i got exception when calling Read():
the exception is that my _dataReader member is null.

That's weird, because i have try-catch block on its initialization, and no exception is caught (i use my loging mechanism to check this).

This behavior is rare, but occures aprox. once a week (i'm running milions of queries per day)

Thanks a lot to anyone who tries to solve this mistery!!

Comment: Don't use `throw ex;`, it loses useful information from the exception. Use just `throw;` instead.

Comment: Are you sure it's `_dataReader` that is `null` and not some other object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the same problem. And it turned out that ExecuteReader () can actually return null in some cases.

I looked up the code of the connector and this is what I found:

```
catch (MySqlException ex)
{

...

// if we caught an exception because of a cancel, then just return null
if (ex.IsQueryAborted)
    return null;
```

Digging a little deeper turns out **IsQueryAborted** is true when the server returns **MySqlErrorCode.QueryInterrupted** or **MySqlErrorCode.FileSortAborted**. And so far it turns out that this is some server problem as at least in my case the problem is not consistent and looks like a multi-threading issue in the server code.

Answer (score -1):

I reviewed the code and I find the only way to get with NULL reader is to have an exception in the initialization code.

As SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader is return an object in all cases and can't return null. Tatiana Racheva had confirmed that by reflection SqlDataReader class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072093/when-would-sqlcommand-executereader-return-null).

The second scenario to have NULL reader is if you are trying to use the reader after your ManagedDataReader object is disposed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Garbage collector never disposes objects. It finalizes objects if they are unreachable, but that wouldn't set the field to null. And if an object is unreachable, that means by definition that you can't reach it.

Comment: It's **MySqlDataReader**, not SqlDataReader...
I can access ManagedDataReader, i can't access _dataReader because it somehow set to null.

thanks anyway...